# Duplicate data after open and close modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using ajax then i'm tring to call append data to modal, but Why my data always return multiple results after I open and close modal?
Can someone help me how to reset that? so I just get 1 results only.

for first time think so good because I just have 1 results, 
[image]

but when I close mymodal and open it again, the last results is not gone. So i got double results like this
[image]

and then this never stop and always increase depend of how much i click and close modal.
[image]

```
 xd[i].addEventListener("click", function(callback){
     console.log($(this));
     $("#mdApart").modal('show');
     $( "#newpend" ).append(`aaa`);
 });
```

Comment: Use `.html()` instead of `.append()`. It replaces instead of appending.

Comment: BTW, the argument to the event listener is an `Event` object, not a callback function.

Comment: ok thanks simple answer and this working fine

Answer (score 0):

It happens because this line is in your click handler: `$( "#newpend" ).append(`aaa`);`
Append means add to the end.

Maybe you want to take that line out the click handler so it only runs once, or else you need to use a different jQuery method, maybe `.replaceWith()` or `.html()`

Comment: `.replaceWith()` is very unlikely to be wanted, because it will remove the DIV itself.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following:

```
$("#newpend").append('aaa');
```

To:

```
$("#newpend").html('aaa');
```

This is because .append() will add content onto the end of the element/content that is already there. By using .html() you will be replacing the content within the element with your new content.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the content div on hide event

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {

    $('#yourContentDiv').html('');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply dispose of the modal once you close it. Bootstrap provides you with a way of doing this.

```js
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myModal').modal('dispose');
});
```